C++ iterator dereference equality preservation
Is there any formal statement in C++ standard (or other trustworthy source) which requires the iterator to return the same value when dereferenced twice?
I see that equality_preservation doesn't explicitly require it (or I miss the point?).
So, what statement in standard exactly implies this expectation:
auto it = /* some iterator */;
auto v1 = *it;
auto v2 = *it;
assert(v1 == v2);


In fact there are some iterators that won't give you the same result each time, an input iterator for example.

@MarkRansom, can you give any such example where deferencing in this way could give different results for std::input_iterator (if you mean exactly it)?

This is required for the pre-c++20 LagacyInputIterator requirement.  From [input.iterators]: The expression (void)*a, *a is equivalent to *a.. I'm not sure it's explicitly required by the C++20 std::input_iterator concept though.

Sorry, I misspoke.  I went looking for an example and checked out std::istream_iterator which states it's not the dereference which changes the value, it's the increment.

Both C++17/C++20 input iterators require the expression *it to be equality-preserving.
[iterator.cpp17] describes the requirements for Cpp17InputIterator:




Expression
Return type
Assertion/note




*a
reference, convertible to T
Preconditions: a is dereferenceable. The expression (void)*a, *a is equivalent to *a. If a == b and (a, b) is in the domain of == then *a is equivalent to *b.




And C++20 std::input_iterator needs to satisfy indirectly_readable, which explicitly requires the semantics in
[iterator.concept.readable]:

Given a value i of type I, I models indirectly_readable only
if the expression *i is equality-preserving.

